# Holds, Defers, Unevaluated & Inactive

Tags: simplifying-expressions, hold

I can program well enough in the Wolfram Language & ignore the nuisances that can pop up... Except Holds, Defers, Unevaluated & Inactive. I never did learn the subtleties of the functions & the attributes. Take this attempt at the implementation of applying L'Hospital Rule:

```
lhospital = 
 Function[{f, x}, 
  Divide @@ ReleaseHold[
    D[Switch[Head[Unevaluated[f]], 
      Times,   {Unevaluated[f][[1]],  1/Unevaluated[f][[2]]}], x] ], 
  HoldFirst]
```

Forgive the obfuscation of perhaps peppering it with excessive Unevaluated & Holds & using Times as the head to decide if it is a fraction.

Well, this almost works for most cases, say but a few:

```
lhospital[a x/(x^2), x]
= 0
```

So I added more Holds. Now, it says I can't index the second member of HoldComplete[f]

```
lhospital = 
 Function[{f, x}, 
  Divide @@ ReleaseHold[
    D[Switch[Head[Unevaluated[f]], 
      Times,   {ReleaseHold[HoldComplete[f][[1]]],  
       ReleaseHold[1/HoldComplete[f][[2]]]}], x] ], HoldFirst]


lhospital[a x/(x^2), x]
Part::partw: Part 2 of HoldComplete[(a x)/x^2] does not exist.

lhospital[x/Sqrt[x], x]
Part::partw: Part 2 of HoldComplete[x/Sqrt[x]] does not exist.
```

So how do I use Holds, Defers, Unevaluated & Inactive to keep the fractional expression being befouled by the aggressive engine in order to obtain the numerator & denominator & derivate them?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you probably want to use Unevaluated.

**Unevaluated**

Unevaluated is perhaps the weirdest (but coolest) in this family. It's not really a plain wrapper like Hold. When the evaluator encounters Unevaluated, it skips evaluating anything inside Unevaluated, and then any other functions that are being applied to the unevaluated expression are applied to this unevaluated form. One consequence of this is that if a subsequent pass of evaluation occurs, it's as if the Unevaluated no longer exists.

Example:

```
List @@ Unevaluated[9/(9^2)]
(* {9, 1/81} *)

Map[hello, Unevaluated[5/((3 + 7)^2)], {-1}]
(* hello[5]*((hello[3] + hello[7])^hello[2])^hello[-1] *)

Unevaluated[9/(9^2)][[2]]
(* 1/81 *)

MapAt[Hold, Unevaluated[5/((3 + 7)^2)], {2, 1, 1}]
(* 5/Hold[3 + 7]^2 *)

Head[Unevaluated[5/((3 + 7)^2)]]
(* Times *)
```

Unevaluated is sort of like having a "transparent" head.

**Hold**

Hold is much simpler to understand. It's just a wrapper that blocks evaluation of anything inside of it. It's a regular wrapper, so when you apply Hold, you get a new expression entirely:

```
Head[Hold[5/((3 + 7)^2)]]
(* Hold *)

List @@ Hold[5/((3 + 7)^2)]
(* {1/20} *)

Hold[5/((3 + 7)^2)][[2]]
(* Hold[5/(3 + 7)^2][[2]] *)
(* There is no second element, and you'll see a "Part 2 of..." message *)

Hold[5/((3 + 7)^2)][[1, 1]]
(* 5 *)

Hold[5/((3 + 7)^2)][[1, 2]]
(* 1/100 *)
```

**Defer**

Defer is almost like a weird hybrid of Unevaluated and Hold. Defer acts like Hold, keeping its contents unevaluated. But if ever a Defer expression is used as input by the user, it will be evaluated as if the Defer were stripped, kind of like Unevaluated. So, Defer is more likely to be used in situations where you're setting up a presentation or user-interface. If you want to dynamically generate input cells, for example.

**Inactive**

Inactive is another one that is more typically used for presentation and UI building. I think it's intended that you use Inactivate rather than Inactive directly.

**Application**

To apply L'Hôpital's rule, we need to get access to the numerator and denominator separately. We'll therefore need to put a Hold* attribute on our function. I'm going to use DownValues rather than a Function like you were trying to do:

```
SetAttributes[ApplyLHopital, HoldAll]
```

Now, in our definition of ApplyLHopital we'll have access to the unevaluated argument. But as soon as we start messing with the argument, things will be evaluated. So, we'll use Unevaluated to interrupt that process. Before we apply derivatives, let's just do some de-structuring to make sure we're handling the expression correctly.

```
ApplyLHopital[exp_, var_Symbol] := 
  {Unevaluated[exp][[1]], Unevaluated[exp][[2, 1]]}

ApplyLHopital[x/x^2, x]
(* {x, x^2} *)
```

We expect the head of the input to be Times, and we expect the denominator to be a Power expression with power of -1. Thus the particular de-structuring I chose.

Okay, let's apply L'Hôpital.

```
ApplyLHopital[exp_, var_Symbol] := 
  D[Unevaluated[exp][[1]], var]/D[Unevaluated[exp][[2, 1]], var]

ApplyLHopital[(E^x - 1)/(x^2 + x), x]
(* E^x/(1 + 2*x) *)
```

Caveat: This provides no protection against inputting the wrong type of argument (i.e. if you don't have a fraction) or against any other violation of preconditions for L'Hôpital. You may want to make this more robust. Also, this is obviously just the first step of L'Hôpital--I've left out the limiting aspect. You could just add another argument for the value to take the limit for.