# Preventing the auto simplification of fractional expression by the engine

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want the Mathematica engine to stop aggressively simplifying fractional/rational expressions. Like, preventing `a x/(x^2)` from becoming `a/x` as it gets passed to a function or entered in the notebook input, when it was not asked to.

There should be an option in the engine about this.

Comment: `Hold[a x/(x^2)]`? I don't think you can stop a function from evaluating `a x/x^2` if it wants to. Maybe `Block[{Times, Power, Plus},
 NumeratorDenominator[a x/(x^2)]
 ]`

Comment: Hey, Michael. I didn't imagine Protected Symbols could affected like that. Thanks for the idea.